# Can't figure out why my cards in tremor (next.js) won't update my front end

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to code my next.js application with Tremor. However, my page on localhost doesn't appear how I wanted it to.

Here is my page.tsx file:

```html
'use client'

import { Card, Text, Subtitle } from '@tremor/react'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <main className="text-6xl">
            <Card>
                <Text> Weather AI</Text>
                <Subtitle>
                    Powered by OpenAI, Next.js 13.3, Tailwind CSS, Tremor 2.0 +
                    More!
                </Subtitle>
                <h1>Let's build a GPT-4 Weather App</h1>
            </Card>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js file:

```html
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
        './node_modules/@tremor/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
                'gradient-conic':
                    'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

And my next.config.js file:

```html
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        externalDir:
            true |
            {
                enabled: true,
                silent: true,
            },
        appDir: true,
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@tremor/react'],
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is how it looks like on my frontend - no cards visible

[image]

Comment: Don't you have any errors in the Console?

Answer (score 0):

Try `@tremor/react` version `2.0`

- Uninstall tremor: `npm un @tremor/react`
- Then install version 2.0: `npm i @tremor/react@2.0`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a proper tailwind.config.js thats the problem.

depending how your project is set up with src folder or no src folder you have to adjust a few lines.

hope this is helpfull I was been struggeling with this one two.

[image]